# The line Txt_EarnedPoint.getText() throws Nullpointer exception (textview)--Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

In Txt_EarnedPoint.getText() line it throws Nullpointer exception why?
Txt_EarnedPoint is a textview. If I remove that line  every think works fine. Plz help me out...

```
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
            android.view.View.OnClickListener {
         private TextView Txt_EarnedPoint;
         private Button saveButton;
         private Button DisableBtn;
         private Button selectbutton;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            TextView  Txt_EarnedPoint=(TextView ) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    public void GetImageId(int Imageid) {
            else if (count == 1
                            && CheckBtnText == selectbutton.getText().toString()) {
                        selectbutton.setBackgroundResource(selectAptImage);
                        selectbutton.setEnabled(false);
                        count = 0;
                        IncCounter += 1;
                        saveButton.setText("0");
                        selectbutton.setText("0");
--error part----------->Txt_EarnedPoint.getText();
                        if (IncCounter == 6) {
                            AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                                    .setTitle("Completed Level 1")
                                    .setMessage("Level Completed")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Why should I stop Playing?", null)
                                    .setNegativeButton("Tired to go on", null).show();
                            HideAllButton();
                        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an object and assigning it to an instance member, you created a local variable which is 'forgotten' when onCreate is done executing.

Change the line:

`TextView Txt_EarnedPoint=(TextView ) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

To:

`Txt_EarnedPoint=(TextView ) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`